# Conectar OBD2 Wifi con Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, objeto, python-3.7, wifi

Tengo este código de la biblioteca OBD2 de Python, y conectado a mi vehículo un OBD2 ELM327 wifi (del mas sencillo)

```
import obd
connection = obd.OBD() # connect to specific OBD-II-wifi Adapter. In our case it is a 
Panda by comma.ai
cmd = obd.commands.SPEED # select an OBD command (sensor)
response = connection.query(cmd) # send the command, and parse the response
print(response.value) # returns unit-bearing values thanks to Pint
print("Hola, final del codigo")
```

Y este es el resultado en la terminal al ejecutar el código

```
[obd.obd] No OBD-II adapters found
[obd.obd] Cannot load commands: No connection to car
[obd.obd] Query failed, no connection available
None
Hola, final del codigo
```

Intente luego con este código

```
import obd
connection = obd.OBD("192.168.0.10", 35000) # connect to specific OBD-II-wifi 
cmd = obd.commands.SPEED # select an OBD command (sensor)
response = connection.query(cmd) # send the command, and parse the response
print(response.value) # returns unit-bearing values thanks to Pint
```

Pero el resultado es que no encontraba dispositivos (comprobé que al IP estubiera bien con mi celular)

No se que otra opcción exista o que puedo hacer